# No utf-8 after getting data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

My problem is: I have no utf-8 marks after I get something from database. Instead I have '?' unless it is 'ó' - then I get nothing.
I have no problems with neither on website (static text works perfectly) nor in database (im MySQL Workbench I can see all letters).

What have I tried:

- files in Notepad++ are utf-8 without BOM
- utf-8 in database
- charset=utf-8 on website
- php_value default_charset "UTF-8" in .htaccess

---

**EDIT**: deleting whole database and starting from scratch helped. No other solution so far.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for some mangled cell.